# Oracle 11g - client and network component were not found Windows Server 2008 x64

Tags: windows, networking, oracle11g, asp-classic, server

I'm having this error frequently. I'm running a ASP 2.0 app on a Windows Server 2008 with Oracle 11.2 x64. I have installed Oracle 11 Client x32 but my Application Pool has the "Allow 32 bits Aplications" config enabled. Also I've reviewed my path and Oracle_home but everything seems normal. My connection provider is MSDAORA. The application eventually shows this error , not always. So I want to know if there are some configs or events logs or configs that I could review to find what the problem is.

Also I tried with the OraOLEDB.Oracle but I have this unknown error for some queries

[OraOLEDB.Oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zus2I.png)

All the necesary dll's are registered.

System Info:
Windows Server 2008 x64
Oracle 11g R2
Oracle 11g Client x32
ASP v2.0
Provider MSDAORA
Application pool allows 32 bit apps
Path:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;...

System has registered ORACLE_HOME key for ASP 2.0 as C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\

The system is on production, web pages are compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by checking and configuring a DNS entry on ODBC Manager. The DNS must point to my oracle client folder.